# Is there a way to change my <header> style when the page reaches certain #anchor point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a question to ask and hopefully get an answer. I am making a one-page portfolio site with four `#anchor` points "pages". The divs have 100% heights so they fill the whole browser height. My header (logo and navigation) has a fixed position. I would like to change the style of my header (my logo and link color) when the user clicks the link or scrolls to the third and fourth `#anchor` point. Could someone help me with this issue because I cannot figure it out?

Comment: Unlike elektroholunder I would not advise to jump to any plug-ins because you could probably write it shorter (and thus faster) for your needs. I am sure I can work something out with jQuery's 'scroll' and 'addClass'.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm on a mobile device now. If still needed, I'll post an answer within 2 hours from now.

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints) might be an easy way to achieve this. It allows you to trigger any kind of action when the user scrolls past certain points on your page.

Answer (score 1):

This will check the height position of the div on the page relative to the div that you are targeting on scroll. This is what I believe you are looking for.

```
$(function(){



$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($('#targetDiv').offset().top >= window.scrollX ){

    }


  })
})
```

Comment: Yet, you should only `/* do something */` when that condition *changes* its value, i.e. caching the previous state.

Comment: That is true, I assumed that would be implied.

Comment: well,i'm just a beginner in js. copy/paste mostly till now.

Comment: Ok, do you understand how to use boolean values?